# *ngFor keeps accessing 2 seperate arrays with the same name concurrently. I only want to Iterate through one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, ngfor

I am trying to Iterate through an Array. The thing is the data is nested and in an object there are 2 arrays with the same name. I would like to Iterate through only one Array. Angular Iterates through both the Arrays concurrently.

I am trying to access and print the **name** from the first instance of **street_group** array only. Angular is print the **name** from both instances of **street_group** array concurrently.

Here is the Data

```
{
    "generated_at": "-",
    "schema": "-",
    "event": {
        "id": "-",
        "scheduled": "-",
        "value": false,
        "timing": {
            "type": "-",
        },
        "season": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "start_date": "-",
            "end_date": "-",
            "year": "-",
        },
        "cycle": {
            "id": "",
            "name": "-",
            "car": {
                "id": "-",
                "name": "-"
            },
            "category": {
                "id": "-",
                "name": "-"
            },
            "type": "-",
            "value": "-"
        },
        "useful": [{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "value": "-",
            "value2": "-",
            "value3": "-",
            "value4": "-"
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "value1": "-",
            "value2": "-",
            "value3": "-",
            "value4": "-"
        }],
        "venue": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "city_name": "-",
            "country_name": "-",
            "map_coordinates": "--",
            "country_code": "-",
            "values": [{
                "name": "-"
            }, {
                "name": "-"
            }]
        }
    },
    "section": [{
        "locale": "-",
        "value": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "country_code": "-"
        },
        "street_group": [{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "locale": "-",
        "value": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "country_code": "-"
        },
        "street_group": [{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }
        ]
}]
}
```

Here is My Component

```
export class LiveComponent implements OnInit {
 allData: {
    generated_at: string;
    section: {
      street_group: { name: string }[];
      locale: string }[];
    event: {
      id: string;
      useful: { name: string }[];
    };
  }[] | null = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {
    }
    ngOnInit(){
this.http.get('http://api.redacted_for_privacy').subscribe(data => {this.allData = [data as any];});
    }
    }
```

This is my HTML

```
<mat-tab-group>

<mat-tab *ngFor="let data of allData" label="{{data.event.useful[0].name}}">

>! The part below is broken

<div class="content">
  <mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let section of data.section">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let street_group of section.street_group | slice:0:2">{{street_group.name}}</mat-list-item> 

  </mat-list>
  
</div>


    </mat-tab>
    
  </mat-tab-group>
```

I have tried adding an Index number to the Section Array since it is the containing array but that breaks the code.

`<mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let section of data.section[0]">`

Where **of** gives this error
**Type '{ street_group: { name: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.ngtsc(2322)**

I was expecting only the first Array to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need a two-dimensional loop (double *ngFor), but a single one on the 0th element.

To print all the names from the first element of section array:

- Remove the outer *ngFor directive on `mat-list`

Only loop through the 0th element of the section inside `mat-list-item`

Your HTML could look like:

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item
    role="listitem"
     *ngFor="let street_group of data.section[0].street_group"
    >{{ street_grp.name }}</mat-list-item
  >
</mat-list>
```

notice `*ngFor="let street_grp of data.section[0].street_group"` to iterate only the elements in `data.section[0]`;

It should also be mentioned here that it can sometimes be useful to flatten nested data. This simplifies access and manipulation of the data.

Answer (score -1):

There is no pipe for your purpose available in Angular. I suggest doing a mapping that will concatenate street_groups in all sections.

```js
// Will output all street_groups in one array
data.section.map((section) => section.street_group).flat()
```